# Google API appears to cause some kind of error when used with `Link` from `react-router` v3

Tags: reactjs, google-api, react-router

My web application uses React and supports Google Auth. I'm getting an error **only in IE11** when using `Link` from `react-router` version 3, and the stack trace suggests that the issue is coming from Google API code.

These are the package versions I'm using:

"react": "^16.8.6"

"react-dom": "^16.8.6"

"react-router": "^3.2.3"

Notes:

- We recently upgraded React to v16, and this error only occurs after
  the upgrade
- The error stops occurring if we don't execute any Google API code.

This is the error and stack trace logged from `componentDidCatch` in the component that uses `Link` from `react-router`.

```
{
   description: "Cannot define property '$jscomp_hidden_0.37733406515879653': object is not extensible",
   message: "Cannot define property '$jscomp_hidden_0.37733406515879653': object is not extensible",
   name: "TypeError",
   number: -2146823211,
   stack: "TypeError: Cannot define property '$jscomp_hidden_0.37733406515879653': object is not extensible
   at f (https://apis.google.com/_/scs/apps-static/_/js/k=oz.gapi.en_US.tkLGB8oygGw.O/m=auth2/rt=j/sv=1/d=1/ed=1/am=wQE/rs=AGLTcCOVrdiUrdoKYhlUTq9WIvZT-VXTAA/cb=gapi.loaded_0:11:79)
   at Object[q] (https://apis.google.com/_/scs/apps-static/_/js/k=oz.gapi.en_US.tkLGB8oygGw.O/m=auth2/rt=j/sv=1/d=1/ed=1/am=wQE/rs=AGLTcCOVrdiUrdoKYhlUTq9WIvZT-VXTAA/cb=gapi.loaded_0:11:181)
   at setInitialDOMProperties (http://10.7.6.197:3000/public/build/scripts/vendor.js:19112:11)
   at setInitialProperties (http://10.7.6.197:3000/public/build/scripts/vendor.js:19328:3)
   at finalizeInitialChildren (http://10.7.6.197:3000/public/build/scripts/vendor.js:20315:3)
   at completeWork (http://10.7.6.197:3000/public/build/scripts/vendor.js:28467:13)
   at completeUnitOfWork (http://10.7.6.197:3000/public/build/scripts/vendor.js:30702:9)
   at performUnitOfWork (http://10.7.6.197:3000/public/build/scripts/vendor.js:30900:5)
   at workLoo"
}
```

I'm having a hard time finding a solution for this, so I would greatly appreciate any insights. Thank you!